# Adding in the beginning of the list confusion

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

Here is the code that adds in the beginning of a doubly linked list:

```
public void insertFirst(long dd)  // insert at front of list
{
      Link newLink = new Link(dd);   // make new link

      if( isEmpty() )                // if empty list,
         last = newLink;             // newLink <-- last
      else
         first.previous = newLink;   // newLink <-- old first
      newLink.next = first;          // newLink --> old first
      first = newLink;               // first --> newLink
}
```

What I dont understand is why when the list `isEmpty()` both the `last` and `first` get assigned to the `newLink`? Isn't it going to look like this then, for example `3->3` (just an example with number `3`). Im really confused about why both of them get assigned to the new node.

Comment: They point to the same `Object`...It will be the first and last because it is the only.

Comment: Barry White: "You are my first, my last, my everything." ;-)

Comment: a word of advice mate, always add `{` and `}` to where appropriate , this way u'll never get to this sort of problems

Comment: To answer simply... it is because you need to be able to iterate in both directions. When you only have one object then either way you iterate you should always end back up at that object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm dividing my answer into two logical reasons and **either or both** of them will answer your doubt.

**1)** Now as to answering your question as it sounds "When inserting a number to an empty list why do we declare the first Node as both `head` & `tail`?"

**There are lot of ambiguities in inserting a number in the second turn.** *Will the next number be insert at first? or at last? or at a particular position?* The following snippet of code will answer your question,

```
Line 1: insertFirst(3); //Sets Node containing 3 as both head and tail. No magic tricks
```

Now either of the following functions may be called depending upon the user's choice:

```
a) Line 2: insertFirst(4);
//Sets Node containing 4 as head and the previous head(3) as it's dual link.
//Notice that there is no need to update the tail as Node containing 3 is already a tail.
b) Line 2: insertLast(4);
//Sets Node containing 4 as tail and the previous tail(3) as it's dual link.
//Notice that there is no need to update the head as Node containing 3 is already a head.
```

This way, the upcoming ambiguity is handly by assigning the first Node as the both `head` and `tail`.

**2)** First things first, **it's a doubly linked list, not a circular linked list** as you showed in your question a `single node(3)` as a `3<>3` depicting `head` and `tail` as individual Nodes. Note that both `head` and `tail` refer to the same Node object which contains the value **3**. You don't have to set any links between your head and tail and vice-versa when creating a doubly-linked list.

The two way links in a DLL are visually represented in form of dual sided angular brackets as follows:

```
head<>node1<>node2<>node3<>tail
```

Notice that the both head and tail, **neither are connected with any links whatsoever in a DLL**. The questions itself has a flaw if this part answers your doubt. But incase you further question about how to maintain a track of displaying nodes in a circular list, use a `size` variable which updates itself at the call of every function.

Answer (score 0):

Get a sheet and a a pen and you'll understand.

If you have an empty list `[]`, following will happen when calling `insert(dd)` :

```
Link newLink = new Link(dd);
// first -> null, last -> null, newLink = {value = dd, previous -> null, next -> null}
last = newLink;
// first = null, last -> newLink, newLink = {value = dd, previous -> null, next -> null}, list = chain from first = []
newLink.next = first;
// first -> null, last -> newLink, newLink = {value = dd, previous -> null, next -> first -> null}, list = chain from first = []
first = newLink;
// first -> newLink, last -> newLink, newLink = {value = dd, previous -> null, next -> null}, list = chain from first = [newLink]
```

Comment: But why when last = newLink the list is still empty?

Comment: Because you read the list by starting at `first` and calling `next` over and over : `first.next.next.next...` until `next` is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

The `newLink` will be assinged into `first` because you have no block (`{`...`}`) in your else, so only `first.previous = newLink` will be performed conditionally, following statements will be unconditional.

Note that you actually want `first` to point at `newLink` in both cases, else you wouldn't be able to reach it iterating from start.